# Proving $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is onto where $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus

Proving $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is onto where $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{x^2+1}$

Proving it was one to one seemed easy, it seems I'm having difficult finding a way to prove it is surjective. Can I get a hint as to what steps I should take?

Comment: Prove it is continuous and use the fact that it goes to $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$y=\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}\iff x^3-yx^2-y=0$$ You finish because the equation being of the third degree, has necessarily a real root.

Comment: That was a nice one!

Comment: @LivaditisAlex: Thank you very much. However it is a very simple solution and actually equivalent to the other answers with limits $\pm \infty$

Comment: Initially I thought so too, but from an algebraic point of view the proof is different and more obvious. You, simply, have to observe that a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$ has even non real roots in total and so the equation $x^3-yx^2-y=0$ has $0$ or $2$ non real roots, which means that it has at least one real root!

Comment: I agree in what I did is more "explicit" however, I repeat, it is "the same"

Comment: @LivaditisAlex Your argument is in a very subtle way circular. You are using the fundamental theorem of algebra, but there is no purely algebraic proof of this theorem. Any proof will require some analysis at some point. In fact, the most algebraic proof that I know is all algebraic except for one fact: that third degree polynomials have a real root! Unfortunately, there is no algebraic proof of that simple fact (unless you assume FTA, but it would not be purely algebraic). The moral is that FTA is a statement that is built on an analytic object, $\Bbb R$, and hence requires some analysis.

Comment: To prove that a third grade polynomial in $\Bbb R [x]$ has in total even non real roots isn' t hard to prove algebraically. You are right that in the proof above I used informally that a third grade polynomial in $\Bbb R [x]$ has all its roots in $\Bbb C$, but I still find it intriguing.

Comment: Very nice solution Piquito!

Answer (score 6):

Show that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty.$$
Then use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that it is onto note that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^3}{x^2+1}
=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{x^{-2}+1}=\infty$$ and similarly $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^3}{x^2+1}=-\infty.$$
Since the function is continuous we conclude by the intermediate value theorem that it is onto.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=x+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-2x}{x^2+1}\right)\quad,\quad D_f=\mathbb{R}$$
set $x=\tan\frac\theta 2$ , we have
$$y=\tan\left(\frac\theta 2\right)-\frac12\sin\theta$$
$$R_f=\mathbb{R}$$